# Surface of revolution parabaloid - question on upper limit of integration

Tags: calculus

I am working on the following problem from MIT OCW single variable calculus.

Here is the question:

Find the area of $y=x^2$, $0\leq x \leq 4$ revolved around the $y$-axis.

I am not concerned with how to evaluate the integral. But here was my setup.

$$A=\int_{0}^{16} 2\pi\sqrt{y} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4y}} dy.$$

However, this is the solution given:

$$A=\int_{0}^{2} 2\pi\sqrt{y} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4y}} dy.$$

How is it that the upper limit of integration in the solution is $2$? My thought was that, because we are integrating with respect to $y$, the upper limit of integration should be precisely when $x=4$, which is when $y$ would be $16$ (i.e. $x=\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{16}=4$). What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: It seems alright.

Comment: I have compared your result with a calculation of the surface area by Pappus's $1^{st}$ Centroid Theorem in the complex plane and find that you are correct.